# Read excel file from StringIO buffer to dataframe with pandas.io.parsers.ExcelFile?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, stringio

I'd like to read a string buffer into a pandas DataFrame. It seems that a good way to do it would be to use pandas' ExcelFile functionality. I've tried to do something like the following:

```
from pandas import ExcelFile as excel_handler
excel_data = excel_handler(StringIO(file_stream.read()).getvalue())
```

From then on, I guess ExcelFile.parse() can be used.

This produces the following error:

```
<class 'openpyxl.shared.exc.InvalidFileException'> [Errno 2] No such
file or directory: '
```

Any ideas on how to read in the file from the buffer?

Comment: What is file_stream? More importantly, why aren't you just using this as `ExcelFile('path/of/excel/file')` or `ExcelFile(file)`...

Comment: It's within the web2py framework. Within the context, it's easier to create the buffer than to specify the filepath. I verified that the StringIO(...) buffer works as expected (i.e. had no problem using it with the xlrd module to open the excel workbook).

Comment: Can you not just pass the buffer?

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing in the code above? Or do you mean to remove getvalue()? That produces an error: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO found

Comment: what about `ExcelFile(file_stream)` ?

Comment: It'll produce the error that it's expecting a filepath. It's kind of hard to believe that there's no way to do it with a buffer...

Comment: Docstring says if takes a file too, which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Using pandas version 0.11.0

Comment: Thanks - you were right that getvalue() doesn't need to be there. The problem was being caused by the presence of filestream.read() earlier in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. Had missed a part earlier in my code where file_stream.read() was being called. Consequently, by the time ExcelFile was being called, an empty string was being passed to it, causing an error. getvalue() needed to be removed. Here's how it should go:

```
from pandas import ExcelFile
excel_data = ExcelFile(StringIO(file_stream.read())
dataframe = excel_data.parse(excel_data.sheet_names[-1])
```

Comment: `.read` returns bytes. so you can use a `BytesIO`  


`excel_data = ExcelFile(BytesIO(file_stream.read())`